# How to Pass Credentials to passport.authenticate?

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I'm trying to secure an API endpoint on a node.js express app that uses passport.

This is my route:

```
router.post('/api/devices', authController.isAuthorized, catchErrors(deviceController.getDevicesAPI));
```

This is my authorization method:

```
exports.isAuthorized = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.json({ message: 'Something is not right ', err, info });
    }
    req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
      if (err) {
          res.send(err);
      }
      next();
    });
  })(req, res);
};
```

From Postman or a separate local server, I get the response:

```
{
    "message": "Something is not right ",
    "err": null,
    "info": {
        "message": "Missing credentials"
    }
}
```

This is the Postman configuration:
[image: Postman config]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally dug it out from [here](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose). `User.authenticate()` is the method I was looking for.

```
exports.isAuthorized =  async (req, res, next) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: username });

  if (!user) {
    res.sendStatus(403);
    return;
  }

  user.authenticate(password, function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
      next();
      return;
    }
    res.sendStatus(403);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your local strategy configured? It seems like a database query problem

As the sample in http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/, please see my comments below

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) { //<--- Here is where you pass the UN&PASS
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) { //<--- Here is the sample code that should find you a user
      if (err) { return done(err); } //<--- Here could be where the response is coming from
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }

      return done(null, user); //<--- Here is the sample code that should let you return that user
    });
  }
));
```

Comment: I'm using mongoose like `const User = mongoose.model('User');`
`passport.use(User.createStrategy());`